# Add a date column in an existing CSV using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv with the following format

```
header1,header2,header3
 data1, data2, data3
 data4, data5, data6
```

I want to add a date column that will make the csv look like this

```
header1,header2,header3, date
 data1, data2, data3, 01/04/2017
 data4, data5, data6, 01/04/2017
```

I tried the following awk command but it adds date in the header row as well. I am newbie with awk and do not know how to get that working

```
mydate=$(date)
awk -v d="$mydate" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$4=d; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
awk -v date="4/1/17" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } NR==1 {print $0 " ,date"} NR>1 {$4=date; print}'
```

NR refers to number of record. like line number.
These in-built variables might be useful for you: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web

Comment: I just tried your solution, its pretty close to what i am looking for but instead of adding a new column at the last, it is appending the date to the 2nd last column in the csv.

Comment: @AshutoshD Just add a new column with the date variable instead. like what you did. `awk -v date="4/1/17" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } NR==1 {print $0 " ,date"} NR>1 {$4=date; print}'` . It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk using conditional operator:

```
$ mydate="5/1/2017"
$ awk -v OFS=", " -v d=$mydate '$0 = $0 OFS ( NR==1?"date":d )' file
header1,header2,header3, date
 data1, data2, data3, 5/1/2017
 data4, data5, data6, 5/1/2017
```

- `OFS=", "`, `FS` may remain default as it is not needed
- date goes in `d` var
- implicit print
- conditional operator to print either `date` on the first record or `d` on all others

Comment: `awk -v OFS=", " -v d=$mydate '$0 = $0 OFS ( NR==1?"date":d )'` (seems the `d` of assignation is missing

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Yeah it was. I wrote it before 7AM, I'm amazed if it was the only thing missing...

Comment: i discover that  content ($0 here) could be changed in "pattern" condition part of the script AND directly used as resulting (line in this case) with your script

Answer (score 0):

sed version is a alternative in this case

```
mydate="6/1/2017";sed -e '1 s/$/,date/;b' -e "s/\$/,${mydate}/" YourFile
```

sed allow an inline edition (no explicit intermediate file) with option `-i` that is sometime usefull